# How to forbid C++ derived class to derive from base, but allow from another derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Given this scenario:

```
class GrandParent {};
class Parent : public GrandParent {};
class Child : public Parent {}; /// Ok
class Child : public GrandParent {}; /// Is it possible to force a compilation error?
```

Comment: If its only purpose is to serve as a base class for `Parent`, why does `GrandParent` exist?

Comment: @PeteBecker For "normal" inheritance probably no reason, but for tricks, sure (base-from-member idiom, EBO, common members for main class and its specialization... this list can go on, and on). For real life example, consider libstdc++'s `std::vector`

Comment: @milleniumbug - there is nothing in this inheritance hierarchy that suggests that it is intended for "tricks". If it is, the question should say so, in order to get more appropriate answers.

Comment: @PeteBecker, as milleniumbug says, it is intended for making some tricks. This is not the hierarchy I want; it's only part of it. But this is irrelevant information for you, and I can say that because you have been the only one that has complained about this; no offense mate. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make the `GrandParent` constructors private and the `Parent` a friend.

```
class GrandParent
{
   friend class Parent;
   private:
   GrandParent() {}
   // ...
};
```

Alternatively, you may trade off polymorphic destruction of `GrandParents`  by making the destructor private:

```
class GrandParent
{
   friend class Parent;
   private:
   virtual ~GrandParent() {}
};

// Invalid Destruction:
GrandParent* p = new Parent;
...
delete p;
```

Comment: Possibly the simplest method. +1

Comment: Only downside here is that `friend` is a blanket solution. I can't think of anything better though...

Comment: I Will give it a try! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to use "template magic".
You should add this code after Child class declaration:

```
 #include <type_traits>

 class Child : public Parent
 {
 };

 static_assert(std::is_base_of<Parent, Child>::value, "Child must derive Parent");
```

If you try change Parent class to GrandParent, compiler gives you error

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Thinking about this, it could be extended to do something more reliably. If the OP has methods that take a parameter of `T *` with a SFINAE check that `T` derives from `GrandParent`, *they* can contain a `static_assert` that `T` derives from `Parent` to reject anything not derived from `Parent`. But that just makes me think: what is the OP trying to accomplish? In that scenario, the easier and saner approach would be to just limit it to `Parent` in the first place and not worry about other `GrandParent`-derived classes.

Comment: I dont understand you thought little bit.

Comment: I mean that if the OP has a `Child2 *` where `Child2` derives directly from `GrandParent`, and the OP passes that `Child2 *` to a template function (possibly as simple a signature as `template <typename T> void f(T *)`) that's intended to only work with `Parent`-derived classes, it's possible to put the check in there. If that function is used widely, that way you wouldn't need to repeat the check for all child classes. But again -- in that case I think something may be wrong with the OP's design.

Comment: Oh, yes, it seems dirty plug.

Comment: @hvd I was adding an answer with something similiar to what you say, however since the first idea was yours I'll let you put that as answer :)

Comment: @DarioOO I commented on this answer because I think the `static_assert` is the most important part of it, and that's @АлександрЛысенко's, so it's okay with me if it just gets put into this answer. :)